# check the angular form is valid in the controller

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I am new to `angularjs`. I have searched for this problem but I found some solutions but none of them were working for me. So, I have a form which is

**HTML**

```
<div class=" row col-xs-12 col-md-12">
    <div id="candidateInfoCorners" ng-show="showcandidateInfo">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-12 info-header">
            <h>Candidate Information</h>
        </div>
        <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" name="Candidateform">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <label class="control-label col-sm-4 candidateNpInDaysLabelPosition" for="noticePeriod">Notice Period In Days :</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                        <input type="number" min="0" ng-model="candidate.noticePeriod" class="form-control ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid-min ng-invalid ng-invalid-required candidateNpInDaysInputPosition"
                            id="noticePeriod" placeholder="Noticeperiod" autocomplete="off" required="">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <label class="control-label col-sm-4 candidateCTCLabelPosition" for="ctc">CCTC In Lakhs :</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                        <input type="number" min="0" decimal-places="" ng-model="candidate.ctc" class="form-control ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid-min ng-invalid ng-invalid-required candidateCTCInputPosition"
                            id="ctc" placeholder="CCTC" autocomplete="off" required="">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <label class="control-label col-sm-4 candidateECTCLabelPosition" for="ectc">ECTC In Lakhs :</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                        <input type="number" min="0" decimal-places="" ng-model="candidate.ectc" class="form-control ng-pristine ng-valid-min ng-invalid ng-invalid-required ng-touched candidateECTCInputPosition"
                            id="ectc" placeholder="ECTC" autocomplete="off" required="">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <label class="col-sm-4 control-label candidateCommunicatioLabelPosition" for="communication">Communication :</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                        <select class="selectpicker form-control ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-invalid ng-invalid-required candidateCommunicatioSelectPosition"
                            ng-model="candidate.communication" name="communication" id="communication" required="">
                            <option value="" selected="">Communication</option>
                            <option value="Good">Good</option>
                            <option value="Average">Average</option>
                            <option value="Poor">Poor</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Now, I have  a controller where I am using this form like -

```
$scope.candidate = {
    noticePeriod: '',
    ctc: '',
    ectc: '',
    communication: ''
};
```

And using it like - `$scope.candidate.noticePeriod` while getting the value.

Now I don't have any `submit` for the form, this is going to happen on some another action .

```
$scope.updateDocument = function() {
    //Here I want to check the Form is valid or not 
    //I tried
    //$scope.candidateform.$valid  but I am getting an error like   
    Cannot read property '$valid' of undefined
}
```

Both functions are in the same controller

Can any one help me with this?

Comment: Yes I tried this But I am getting     Cannot read property '$valid' of undefined

Comment: are you want to submit the value? I think so that only you are check you form. am i right?

Comment: I want  to submit the values but that will be on the update function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You need to use ng-form**

This is how I do it.

I make a parent property like

```
$scope.myforms = {
    Candidateform: {}
};

//HTML will be
<ng-form name="myForms.CandidateForm">...</ng-form>

//TO VALIDATE I DO IT LIKE THIS

$scope.myForms.CandidateForm.$submitted = true // This will run the validators as well, this means form has been submitted.

//OR TO SUBMIT IT PROGRAMATICALLY
$scope.myForms.CandidateForm.$valid
```

You have some errors in your code, You name your form "**Candidateform**" and then in controller you are only using $scope.candidate. Change that to $scope.CandidateForm

```js
function Controller($scope) {
    $scope.master = {};
    $scope.user = {
         name: "",
         email: ""
    };
    $scope.update = function(user) {
        //$scope.master = angular.copy(user);
        console.log($scope.master)
    };
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html ng-app>
<div ng-app="demo1">
  <div ng-controller="Controller">
    <ng-form novalidate class="simple-form" name="master">
        <legend>User Profile</legend>
        <div class="control-group-error">
            <label class="control-label" for="input-error">Name</label>
            <div class="controls">    
                <input type="text" name="username" ng-model="user.name">
                <span class="help-inline">Please correct the error</span>
            </div>
            <label>E-mail</label>
            <input type="email" name="email" ng-model="user.email">
        </div>
    </ng-form>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="update(user)">Save</button>
      <br />
    <pre>{{master.$valid}}</pre>
  </div>
</div>
</html>
```

Comment: What should I use ?  you are saying to use  $scope.CandidateForm = {  noticeperiod: ''}

Comment: You can use any name but keep it same in html and controller.

Comment: There will be no button for  a form

Comment: That is just an example, I have given you the code and direction how you can fix your code. You need to change your forms to ng-forms and then name should be same in controller and html and initialize your form first and to validate use $scope.yourform.$valid

Comment: You are welcome, don't forget to accept it as answer and upvote if it helped you.

Comment: when I make some change in the html and then reloads the app then it works and after that when I logout without changing in the html then it is not working

Comment: @ganeshk I can't tell whats going on in your code. How you are using it and what you are doing. As per this question and the given code your problem will get solved by using the above code. My code will work surely without any issues. If you are still having issues then I will say make a new question related to that problem and I will gladly help you and yes show more code if you want your problem to get solved. We don't know how you are using update func and where you are using it, so we can't help regarding this problem.

Comment: Okay thanks  for all help.  I am using now  $scope.myforms = {
    Candidateform: { noticeperiod:' ', ctc: ''   }
};   .

Comment: $scope.myforms = { Candidateform: { noticeperiod:' ', ctc: '' } }; Didn't you tried it in the starting when I told you so? Well, I am glad your code is working. Don't forget to upvote and select as answer.

Comment: TypeError: Cannot read property 'CandidateForm' of undefined
 Getting this error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160271/discussion-between-hey24sheep-and-ganeshk).

Comment: Update your question to show more code, we can't help unless we know what you are doing.